# Cannot import beautiful soup with all packages installed

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, import

I have installed anaconda in my laptop as well. So it returned me this message

ImportError: cannot import name 'beautifulsoup' from 'bs4' (C:\Users\jinfe\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4_*init*_.py)

Comment: try `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

Comment: it works!! thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Here you are trying to import 'beautifulsoup' but we can see on the [docs of the library](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that the name to import is 'BeautifulSoup' instead [image: beautiful soup usage]

Comment: Sure it works!!! thanks!!!